# vcdExtra::datasets not working on some Packages

Tags: r

R3.6.1, vcdExtra 0.7.1

```
vcdExtra::datasets("caret")
```

> Error in get(x) : object 'GermanCredit' not found

`vcdExtra::datasets` fails on some packages like "caret". 
Am I missing something?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only require the dataset of German Credit, try this code:

```
library(caret)
data("GermanCredit")
GermanCredit
```

And you will get:

```
Duration Amount InstallmentRatePercentage ResidenceDuration Age NumberExistingCredits NumberPeopleMaintenance Telephone
1         6   1169                         4                 4  67                     2                       1         0
2        48   5951                         2                 2  22                     1                       1         1
3        12   2096                         2                 3  49                     1                       2         1
4        42   7882                         2                 4  45                     1                       2         1
5        24   4870                         3                 4  53                     2                       2         1
```

Please, comment if it is what you need.

Regards,

Alexis

Answer (score 0):

This is the sequence of commands that I need to run for a correct functioning of `vcdExtra::datasets("caret")`

```
library(evtree)
library(caret)
data(Sacramento)
data(tecator)
data(BloodBrain)
data(cox2)
data(dhfr)
data(oil)
data(mdrr)
data(pottery)
data(scat)
data(segmentationData)
vcdExtra::datasets("caret")
```

The output is

```
               Item      class     dim                                                   Title
1      GermanCredit data.frame 1000x21                                      German Credit Data
2        Sacramento data.frame   932x9                               Sacramento CA Home Prices
3            absorp     matrix 215x100          Fat, Water and Protein Content of Meat Samples
4          bbbDescr data.frame 208x134                                Blood Brain Barrier Data
5              cars data.frame    50x2 Kelly Blue Book resale data for 2005 model year GM cars
6         cox2Class     factor     462                                     COX-2 Activity Data
7         cox2Descr data.frame 462x255                                     COX-2 Activity Data
8          cox2IC50    numeric     462                                     COX-2 Activity Data
9              dhfr data.frame 325x229                 Dihydrofolate Reductase Inhibitors Data
10        endpoints     matrix   215x3          Fat, Water and Protein Content of Meat Samples
11       fattyAcids data.frame    96x7               Fatty acid composition of commercial oils
12           logBBB    numeric     208                                Blood Brain Barrier Data
13        mdrrClass     factor     528         Multidrug Resistance Reversal (MDRR) Agent Data
14        mdrrDescr data.frame 528x342         Multidrug Resistance Reversal (MDRR) Agent Data
15          oilType     factor      96               Fatty acid composition of commercial oils
16     potteryClass     factor      58               Pottery from Pre-Classical Sites in Italy
17             scat data.frame  110x19                               Morphometric Data on Scat
18        scat_orig data.frame  122x20                               Morphometric Data on Scat
19 segmentationData data.frame 2019x61                                  Cell Body Segmentation
```

Comment: This is not useful to me because there are other packages affected like: "mlbench"  
The "caret" was just an example.